# Django command - django-admin command not working

Tags: django

i have tried to install django using below three command. Now when i execute the django-amdin command then its showing me below error. Even i cant see the django-admin --version.

```
sudo apt install python3.8
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
pip3 install Django ( Its successfully installed )
Now when i execute any command related to django-admin then its showing below error:

Error is : 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dev/.local/bin/django-admin", line 7, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
  File "/home/dev/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from django.apps import apps
  File "/home/dev/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .config import AppConfig
  File "/home/dev/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 7, in <module>
    from django.utils.deprecation import RemovedInDjango41Warning
  File "/home/dev/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 5, in <module>
    from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async
  File "/home/dev/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py", line 114
    launch_map: "Dict[asyncio.Task[object], threading.Thread]" = {}
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Please help here if anyone have an idea.

Comment: Your command shows you install python3.8 but you are running python3.5.

Comment: yes , i have used the command python3.8 but its installed 3.5. Its also showing me Python 3.5.2.

Comment: so what i need to do here. Manage.py not available because  when i execute django-admin startapp  then its showing me same error while used the django-admin.

Comment: Try `python3.8 django-admin.py .....`

Comment: its showing me this one error : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django

Comment: Use `pip3.8 install ...` when you use `pip3 install ...` i believe it is using python3.5. Also you should _really_ be using a **virtual environment** here, which it appears you don't.

Comment: oh ok let me try this.

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer to this question since I had the same problem, my Django version required python 3.6+. I don't know how he found that out but it solved it for me.

[link to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67543633/launch-map-dictasyncio-taskobject-threading-thread-error-while-cre)
by commenter Siddhartha Dutta

"Python 3.5.6 will not work, you will need at least Python3.6+ in your virtual environment, for this Django version. –
Siddhartha Dutta
May 25 at 14:21"

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30319772)

Answer (score 0):

> you can uninstall asgiref first:
> python3 -m pip uninstall asgiref
> and install django again:
> python3 -m pip install django