# launch_map: "Dict[asyncio.Task[object], threading.Thread]" = {} -Error While Creating Django Project

Tags: python, django, django-models

When I tried to create Django project in virtual Environment, I am getting below Error,

C:\Users\new\Desktop\Desktop Files\Django Projects>activate myDjangoEnv

(myDjangoEnv) C:\Users\new\Desktop\Desktop Files\Django Projects>django-admi
n startproject first_project
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\new\anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 7, in 
from django.utils.deprecation import RemovedInDjango41Warning
File "C:\Users\new\anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 5, in 
from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async

File "C:\Users\new\anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\asgiref\sync.py", line 114
launch_map: "Dict[asyncio.Task[object], threading.Thread]" = {}
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Please help me on this.Thanks in advance

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: In my Local Python version is Python 3.9.1.

In my Virtual Environment named mtDjangoEnv it is Python 3.5.6

(myDjangoEnv) C:\Users\new\Desktop\Desktop Files\Django Projects>python
Python 3.5.6 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Aug 26 2018, 16:05:27) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

Comment: Python 3.5.6 will not work, you will need at least `Python3.6+` in your virtual environment, for this Django version.

Answer (score 0):

1 Create a new virtual environment.

2 install the latest version of python and other packages.

3 install the latest version of Django

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on mac or linux you should add 4th step to [https://stackoverflow.com/users/15373241/sahil-sharma's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15373241/sahil-sharma%27s) answer

1 Create a new virtual environment.

2 install the latest version of python and other packages.

3 install the latest version of Django

4 source activate yourDjangoEnvironment.

Please take a look about [source activate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49600611/python-anaconda-should-i-use-conda-activate-or-source-activate-in-linux) in this previous question :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).